# Displaying intermediate terms in a β-reductor

Tags: io, scheme, lambda-calculus

Consider the following β-reductor:

```
(define (normalize v)
  (set! count 0)
  (set! reflected '())
  (reify v))

(define (reify v)
  (if (memq v reflected)
      (v cancel)
      (let ((x (gensym)))
    (ABS x (reify (v (reflect x)))))))

(define (reflect e)
  (let ((f (lambda (v)
         (if (eq? v cancel)
         e
         (reflect (APP e (reify v)))))))
    (set! reflected (cons f reflected))
    f))

(define (APP e1 e2) `(,e1 ,e2))

(define (ABS x e) `(lambda (,x) ,e))

(define reflected '())

(define count 0)

(define cancel '(cancel))

(define (gensym)
  (set! count (+ 1 count))
  (string->symbol (string-append "x" (number->string count))))
```

I would like to analyze its β-reduction order. However, since I'm not too savvy with Scheme, I would like to see the intermediate terms (right now it only prints the end result) it calculates as pure lambda expressions. I know how to display a line, but I am unable to squeeze a `(display term) (newline)` in the right spot.

Below are two simple terms that can be used to verify a solution - Church `one` (`λfx.f x`) and `succ` (`λnfx.f (n f x)`) (I hope I wrote them correctly in Scheme):

```
(define One
  (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f x))))

(define succ
  (lambda (n) (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f ((n f) x))))))

(normalize (succ One))
```

Is it possible to display the intermediate terms calculated by this reductor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, This is a big-step NBE algorithm (meaning "all at once"). it works by reflecting your term language into the host languages to piggy back on the hosts execution engine.

Comment: I'll need to educate myself on this a little bit; is this equivalent or comparable to any pure lambda calculus evaluation order?

Comment: It depends on the host language's evaluation order, strict in this case. It would implemen't lazy lambda calculus in a lazy host language, strict in a strict host language. relevant citation would be [Definitional Interpreters for Higher-Order Programming Languages - Reynolds]